# Why doesn't getopt() get the first argument when process is started from another process?

Tags: c, windows

When I start a process from another process using `CreateProcess`,  I am unable to get the first argument that was supplied when using `getopt()`.

Comment: When calling CreateProcess, try leaving lpApplicationName = NULL, and only use lpCommandLine:  CreateProcess(NULL, CommandLine, ... , with the app name as the first argument in CommandLine[]. That may solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Just found an hack into it. getopt() parses the first command as the application name. When a process is started from another process using CreateProcess() the first argument received in the child process is not the application name but the first command that was given to it.
Ordinary case from terminal: 
.app arg1 arg2. In this case argv[0] is app, argv[1] is arg1....

Starting from process using CreateProcess():
The application name and arguments are provide separately to the function CreateProcess().
Assuming the argument string is "arg1 arg2" trying to access argv[0] gives arg1 other than the application name. After parsing the options using getopt(), trying to get the first argument(argv[optind]) we get arg2. This points out that getopt() ignores the first argument since it is usually the app name. To be able to obtain the first command add any stupid argument before the actual arguments.
e.g. Argument string: "stupid arg1 arg2". This way getopt() easily thinks that stupid is the application name.

Comment: That should be _The operational arguments start with `argv[1]`_, I think.

Comment: The vector of arguments you pass to the child process needs to include `argv[0]` set to the name of the process.  The operational arguments start with `argv[1]` (fixing typo).  The C standard says that's what's required.  If you can't determine the command name, you have to provide an empty string.  The rule is simple: `argv[0]` is the name of the program being executed.  And `argv[argc]` must be a null pointer, too.

Comment: @TripeHound: Indeed so — a typo I fixed just before I saw your comment.

Comment: Putting the application name at the start of the `lpCommandLine` string isn't a hack.  If you read the documentation for CreateProcess, that's exactly what it tells you to do!  (It's what the command prompt does, too.)